# Bundle install not working offline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler

I got this issue. I think got bundler installed. And since than I am not able to bundle install while creating app in RoR, or bundle install direct within the project.
Kindly help me if you got any issue and found the solution for this.

```
enter code here     :run  bundle install
:Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
:Error Bundler::HTTPError during request to dependency API
:Fetching full source index from https://rubygems.org/
:Could not reach https://rubygems.org/
```

Answer (score 29):

If you have your gems installed, you can use `bundle install --local`. It is not require internet connection

Comment: Thanks Caulfield. That really worked. Great!! Awesome.. I was looking for this result..

Answer (score 3):

The following method works for me.

```
$ rails new blog -B # -B tells rails not to run bundle install
cd blog
$ bundle install --local
Edit the GemFile and uncomment the line "therubyracer"
$ rails server
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.0.0 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2013-09-28 19:09:35] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2013-09-28 19:09:35] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2013-05-14) [i686-linux]
[2013-09-28 19:09:35] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=1635 port=3000
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to be online so that bundler can check with rubygems that you have the latest gems and download them if necessary.

Comment: Hi,
It was working offline initially in Ubuntu. I use Aptana IDE, I guess I installed bundler, or tried Spree CMS to configure, from than the offline bundle install isn't working. But now even my windows, Aptana IDE too got the same issue. 

run  bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Error 
Bundler::HTTPError during request to dependency API
Fetching full source index from 
https://rubygems.org/
Network error while fetching 
https://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/sqlite3-1.3.6.gemspec.rz

Kindly help if I did any mistake

Comment: I was able to bundle install even without being online.