# Octopress installation stops during bundle install

Tags: ruby, bundler, octopress

I follow the instructions of [Octopress installation](http://octopress.org/docs/setup/).
but it stops after:

```
bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from http ://rubygems.org/
Fetching source index from http ://rubygems.org/
```

It doesn't continue after that.

after a very long time,it shows up error message:

```
Network error while fetching http ://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/active_data-0.1.0.gemspec.rz
```

How can I get over this problem?

anyway,

```
bundle install --local
```

doesn't work. it would show up error message:

```
Could not find rake-0.9.2.2 in any of the sources
```

And I'm not behind any http proxy.
If this is caused by a network connection problem, how do I install bundles offline?

---

Thanks, Problem solved.
I change the Gemfile from http to https, it finally works.

Comment: It takes a long time to complete... why don't you run it again, and wait for couple of minutes this time? BTW, if you did wait and still not get response, are you under any http proxy?

Comment: It seems like a bug in bundler... https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues/2379. Try running `bundle install --local` if gems are already installed as given here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10635065/bundle-install-not-working-offline

Comment: Is this a typo? `http ://rubygems.org/`

Comment: is the source correct? i see a whitespace between 'http' and '://rubygems.org/'

Comment: Yeah... the source URL seems to be wrong. Just go to the Gemfile and edit the source line (first one) to `source 'https://rubygems.org'` and try it again. Read more about it here: http://gembundler.com/v1.3/gemfile.html

Answer (score 1):

Like Jorge and HungryCoder suggested, the reason behind this must be that space between `http` and `://rubygems.org` inside your Gemfile, due to which your bundler can't resolve the address to fetch those gems.

Just go to the Gemfile inside the main Octopress directory and edit the source line (first one) to

`source 'https://rubygems.org'`

and try it again.

Your Gemfile would look something like [this](https://github.com/imathis/octopress/blob/master/Gemfile):

```
source "http://rubygems.org"

group :development do
  gem 'rake', '~> 0.9'
  gem 'rack', '~> 1.4.1'
  gem 'jekyll', '~> 0.12'
  gem 'rdiscount', '~> 1.6.8'
  gem 'pygments.rb', '~> 0.3.4'
  gem 'RedCloth', '~> 4.2.9'
  gem 'haml', '~> 3.1.7'
  gem 'compass', '~> 0.12.2'
  gem 'sass-globbing', '~> 1.0.0'
  gem 'rubypants', '~> 0.2.0'
  gem 'rb-fsevent', '~> 0.9'
  gem 'stringex', '~> 1.4.0'
  gem 'liquid', '~> 2.3.0'
end

gem 'sinatra', '~> 1.3.5'
```

You can read more about using Gemfile [here](http://gembundler.com/v1.3/gemfile.html).